# Bash script for deleting duplicate files

Tags: bash, file, scripting, duplicates, delete-file

Im new to bash scripting but I believe it would be the best way to delete duplicate image files in a given directory with names such as follows:

```
IMG_151.jpg
IMG_151 2.jpg
IMG_151 3.jpg
IMG_152.jpg
IMG_152 2.jpg
IMG_152 3.jpg
....
```

In other words, I would like to loop through the directory and delete all the image files with an appended number to it. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away with just:

```
rm *\ *
```

Assuming all of the duplicate files have a space in them and that none of the originals do. A bit more complicated, but safer:

```
rm IMG_???\ ?.jpg
```

If you prefer. Regardless, no loops necessary.

Comment: The duplicates indeed all had spaces. Very legit soln. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First to be sure, `ls` to see what the regex is finding:

```
ls IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9]\ [0-9].jpg
```

Then if its accurate you can delete them:

```
rm IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9]\ [0-9].jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a regex and `find` command (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

This command search all the files with ".jpg" extension that starts with "IMG_" concatenated with a number from 0 to 999 and look for a space and a number from 0 to 9.

```
find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/IMG_[0-999][[:space:]][0-9]*.jpg"
```

If you wish to delete this files add the rm command:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/IMG_[0-999][[:space:]][0-9]*.jpg" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Before delete this files use the command to see if the regex is correct.

If you have some permission problem prepend `sudo`.